# Using Spring Social using simple Servlets

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-social

For performance reasons, we are using simple Servlets to serve JSON. 
Reason is performance - this will give more info: http://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/#section=data-r5 . Trust me, this is true.

We want to use Spring social for two things:
1. Allow a user to login thru linkedin
2. Make API calls to linkedin REST APIs upon a request that arrived to a servlet

I'm looking for examples on how to do it. Did anyone use spring social without spring MVC ? 
Don't get me wrong, Spring is great but we don't really need it. 
We agree to use the Spring MVC mechanism(controller based) for login purposes but only if it will not harm the over all performance of standard servlets(this might be a different question).

Thanks,
Elad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the OAuth dance is split between ConnectController/ProviderSignInController and ConnectSupport. Even then, the controllers only facilitate the redirect portion of the dance and the actual exchange of verifiers and credentials for tokens takes place in ConnectSupport.

Therefore, there's really no reason you can't recreate what ConnectController and ProviderSignInController does as a plain servlet and leverage what's already in ConnectSupport to do the backend work. And you can still leverage the stuff in the connection repositories as well for persisting the connections. You'll just need to write a servlet that handles the redirects and you should be good.

If you *do* implement such a thing, I'd be interested in seeing what you come up with.

Comment: Also, I don't question your desire for greater performance, except to say that you should report your findings to the Spring MVC team and see if they can help you squeak some more performance out of the framework. A framework on top of servlets will likely never be more performant the plain servlets, but maybe it could be close enough to still use the framework.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. I guess it means that it can work, but after a deep look at the documentation it is looks too complicated for my level...thanks anyway !